# Error message after installing fontmake: "No module named py23"

Tags: python-2.7, module, ttx-fonttools

I've installed, uninstalled, reinstalled FontTools and Fontmake via pip.

However, whenever I try to call Fontmake in terminal I get the following error. Py23 appears to be a Fonttools dependency, which is also installed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fontmake", line 9, in 
    load_entry_point('fontmake==1.3.1.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'fontmake')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    entry = **import**(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['**name**'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fontmake/**main**.py", line 18, in 
    from fontmake.font_project import FontProject
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fontmake/font_project.py", line 37, in 
    from defcon import Font
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/defcon/**init**.py", line 10, in 
    from defcon.objects.font import Font
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/defcon/objects/font.py", line 6, in 
    from ufoLib import UFOReader, UFOWriter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ufoLib/**init**.py", line 6, in 
    from fontTools.misc.py23 import basestring, unicode
ImportError: No module named py23

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing Fonttools from the source files, instead of installing with pip.